# Why is my CommandParameter sometimes (but not always) null despite being declared in markup?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, command, relaycommand

I have code that looks roughly like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Do Something"
          Command="{Binding ChangeSomeEnumValue}"
          CommandParameter="{x:Static someNamespace:SomeEnum.EnumValue}" />
```

In the viewmodel used as the DataContext:

```
// RelayCommand takes an Action<object> to be used by Execute, and a
// Predicate<object> to be used by CanExecute.
this.ChangeSomeEnumValue = new RelayCommand(
    p => this.CurrentEnumValue = (SomeEnum)p,
    ChangeSomeEnumValuePredicate);

...

bool ChangeSomeEnumValuePredicate(object commandParameter)
{
    Console.WriteLine(commandParameter);
    var enumValue = (SomeEnum)commandParameter;
    ...
    return true;
}
```

When the `MenuItem` is first displayed, the output is:

```
EnumValue
EnumValue
EnumValue
```

When I click on the `MenuItem` "EnumValue" is printed 3 more times, then I get a `NullReferenceException` on the line `var enumValue = (SomeEnum)commandParameter` (`commandParameter` is null).

I can't for the life of me think of a reason why `CommandParameter` would be correct the first several times `CanExecute` is called, but `null` another time. What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been some issue with Context Menu's Commands predicate function which i have faced. This might help you out -
[WPF CommandParameter is NULL first time CanExecute is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335849/wpf-commandparameter-is-null-first-time-canexecute-is-called)

[ICommand.CanExecute being passed null even though CommandParameter is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027224/icommand-canexecute-being-passed-null-even-though-commandparameter-is-set)

Comment: The second link appears to the same problem that I am having. It appears it is a bug in WPF itself. I was able to work around the issue by returning `false` when `commandParameter` is `null`, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Yeah. It's a bug. I reduced my problem to just a list of buttons. It worked so I stared building up the original page around that list. I built it up completely and now it works. It is the exact same XAML character for character as the original view. This is most certainly a bug.  I wish I had reproducible proof I would report it. These are the types of bugs that never get fixed.